# Gradient bounds on Newtonian potentials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Suppose $N \ge 3$ and let $\Phi(x):= C_N |x|^{2-N}$ is the fundamental solution.  Let $\Omega$ denote a bounded domain in $ R^N$.

Consider $ -\Delta u(x) = f(x) $ in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.   Let $ \delta(x):=dist(x,\partial \Omega)$.

Question I am interested in.  I am interested in obtaining bounds on $ \| \nabla u \|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ for certain ranges of $p$ assuming, for instance,  $ \| f \delta^\alpha \|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ is finite and where $ \alpha \in [0,1]$.

If $ \alpha=0$ it seems (at least formally) that one can just play with Newtonian potential of $f$ to get the desired estimates.   If $ \alpha=1$ i understand the duality proof on how to obtain $L^p$ bounds on the solution $u$;  but to be its not clear whether one can use the Newtonian potential to obtain bounds on gradient of $u$.

So for a precise question set $v(x):= (f \ast \Phi)(x)$ and assume $  \| f \delta^\alpha \|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ is finite.  For what values of $ \alpha$ can we obtain a gradient $L^p$ bound on the full domain $\Omega$.  Moreover  do the estimates hold on solutions of the above pde with $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. 
I am not very familiar with Newtonian potentials and so i am sorry if the above is complete nonsense. 
regards
greg

Comment: I am also assuming $\Omega$ is smooth domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

[1] J. I. Díaz and J.-M. Rakotoson, “On the differentiability of very weak solutions with right hand side data integrable with respect to the distance to the boundary,” J. Funct. Anal., vol. 257, no. 3, pp. 807–831, 2009.

Comment: thank you very much for the reference.  I will take a look and see if i understand their results and whether i can apply them.

Comment: @Math604 They use a lot of intermediate spaces at points, but the statement of the theorem should be clear enough. Everything is stated in terms of very weak solutions.